# Watson Custom sentiment

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson, watson-discovery

I am new to Watson, and have a fairly basic question. I understand that custom models can be created for discovery, but not sure about the sentiment model

In my domain there are certain verbs and adjectives that indicate positives and negatives, and Id like to train the sentiment model to identify these. Is this posible?

Thanks in advance,
JDG

Answer (score 0):

For sentiment models, I'm assuming you're referring to [Watson NLU](https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/natural-language-understanding/). If so, then yes, you can create custom models via Watson Knowledge Studio and use them in the API. Full documentation can be found [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/customizing.html#customizing).